# Для чего нужны Middleware?

Tags: python

Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в разработке телеграмм ботов и дошёл до такой темы, как middleware и не особо понимаю для чего они нужны. В оф. документации библиотеки aiogram по этой теме есть пример, в котором реализован анти-спам. Но тогда вопрос вот в чём, почему бы это не реализовать напрямую в функции? И я часто видел в примерах, как многие проверки проводятся именно в middleware.
Для чего необходимо проводить проверки именно там? И для чего собственно вообще нужны middleware? Не обязательно для телеграмм ботов, мне бы хотя бы абстрактно понять что это такое и для чего.

Comment: Если функций сотни, вы замучаетесь пихать антиспам в каждую

Comment: Почему бы не создать декоратор тогда для антиспама? И просто навесить на функции.

Comment: То же самое: если функций сотни, вы замучаетесь вешать декоратор на каждую

Comment: Хотя, конечно, декораторы тоже используются, когда нужно навесить фичу на _некоторых_ функциях. А вот если надо на _всех_, то middleware практичнее